# ProgressView not showing in all UICollectionViewCells

Tags: ios, progress-bar, uicollectionviewcell

My problem is that the ProgressView only shows up in the first 2 cells. What is wrong with my code?

**Note:** My CollectionView scrolls horizontally and each cell covers the whole screen. I think this might have something to do since I tried showing all cells in the same view and they work fine. All ProgressViews show.

**EDITED CODE:**

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
VestimentaDetailCell *cell = (VestimentaDetailCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.progressView.hidden = NO;
[cell.progressView setProgress:0.02];

PFFile *storeLooks = [self.vestimenta objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%ld", (long)indexPath.item]];

NSMutableString *precio = [NSMutableString string];
for (NSString* precios in [self.vestimenta objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"precios_%ld", (long)indexPath.item]]) {
[precio appendFormat:@"%@\n", precios];}

[storeLooks getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
if (!error && data.length > 0) {

cell.imageFile.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

} else {

    cell.progressView.hidden = YES;

        }

} progressBlock:^(int percentDone) {
    float percent = percentDone * 0.02;
    [cell.progressView setProgress:percent];
    if (percentDone == 100){
        cell.progressView.hidden = YES;
    } else {
    cell.progressView.hidden = NO;
 }

}];

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing the progress view from the cell, you should simply `setHidden:YES`.

This way when the cells are reused, the progress view will be present and you can then `setHidden:NO` when you want to start loading stuff in that cell.

Also be careful with progress blocks inside your cells when they are reused. Remember to either cancel the loading operation if the cell is reused, or make sure the progress block only continues updating it's cell if the cell hasn't been reused for a different data item.

---

So for example I would set the progress to `0.` where you're showing the progress view like so:

```
VestimentaDetailCell *cell = (VestimentaDetailCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.progressView.hidden = NO;
[cell.progressView setProgress:0.];
```

And because you're hiding the progressView when the data is finished loading, I would just get rid of this code in the progressBlock:

```
  if (percentDone == 100){
    cell.progressView.hidden = YES;
  } else {
    cell.progressView.hidden = NO;
  }
```

Comment: Could you help me with the following code? I have updated my code but it seems to have the same problem. Only the first two cells use the progress view, the rest are blank. I also have a like button and noticed that when I've liked an image.. the Next Next image also gets liked and skips by 2 images. Same as the progressView. Note: This only happens when I have the collectionView to be scrolled Horizontally.

Comment: No, it deletes the progressView Completely. I have though added the progress at 0.02 in your first part of the code and It seems to be working. I'm still testing it on different circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to the cells being reused as they come on screen.  Since you are removing the progressView from the cell [cell.progressView removeFromSuperview] , once it is dequeued, it is still missing.  You could try overriding the prepareForReuse method in your VestimentaDetailCell class to add it back so that all dequeued cells are brought back to their original state.